# Predictable Quadratic Variation of $M^2-4\int_{0}^{t}W^2_s ds$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, quadratic-variation

Let the stochastic process given by $K=M^2-4\int_{0}^{t}W^2_s ds $ , where M is a stochastic process $(M_t)_{ t \geq 0}$ given by : $Μ_t=W^2_t-t$ and W is a standard Brownian Motion.

I need to calculate the predictable quadratic variation of K, < K >

My progress so far is proving that $4\int_{0}^{t}W^2_s ds=<X>$ where $X=W^2_t$ but i dont know how to move on to calculate < K >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral with respect to $ds$ is a finite variation process by definition, hence has zero quadratic variation. So the only contribution will be from the $M_t$ term.

Note that by definition, for a continuous local martingale $X$, the quadratic variation $[X]_t$ is the unique finite variation process such that $X^{2}_{t}-[X]_t$ is itself a continuous local martingale.

But you can check that $M_t = W_{t}^{2}-t$ is actually a true martingale, and so is $M_{t}^{2}-\mathbb{E}[M_{t}^{2}]$. You can verify this directly from the definitions (it holds for adapted processes with independent increments more general than Brownian motion, subject to integrability). So by uniqueness, $[M]_t =  \mathbb{E}[M_{t}^{2}]$.

We can calculate :
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[M_{t}^{2}] = \mathbb{E}[W_{t}^{4}]-2t\mathbb{E}[W_{t}^{2}]+t^2.
\end{equation}
By second and fourth moments of a normal distribution, $\mathbb{E}[W_{t}^{2}] =t$, $\mathbb{E}[W_{t}^{4}]=3t^2$.
Hence, $[M]_t =  2t^2 = [K]_t.$

Comment: Thanks for your great answer!